# I can't see objects added from the menu

Tags: 3d-view, objects

When I add objects to my scene from the add menu at the top I cant see them. They are toggled as visible in the outline and they are positioned so that I should be able to see them. However if I use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> I can see them fine. This isn't a problem except that when I try to add an imported model it is also invisible.

EDIT:
Here is my blend file. You can see everything except for the cube object. The cube however is set to visible in the outline and it is in the first layer. It doesnt show up in either the 3D view or the render
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33167

EDIT 2:
I was just playing around with some other stuff and the cube randomly just showed up in the render, but it is still not in the viewport

Comment: Is this a problem with the placement of the 3D cursor?

Comment: Just a thought. Are they 2D objects, like planes and circles? I've experienced this problem with such objects, but never with 3D objects.

Comment: Also, are you on the correct layer? Could you upload your .blend to http://www.pasteall.org/blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were in local view (<kbd>Numpad</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>).

Comment: To me it looked like the cube had no vertices. It really said verts:0/0

Comment: Nother thing would be to leave edit mode and just add the cube apart from the mesh.

Comment: @VinceScalia Yes... but the issue would still be there.

Comment: This is correct; But only while you're in edit. I saw the cube with my own three eyes when added in object mode. No idea why. Local view's the real deal though.